# How do I return a custom error message to PHP's cURL?

Tags: php, perl, curl, cgi

I'm using PHP cURL-multi to make HTTP requests on another server.  The scripts on the other server are in Perl/CGI.  In the case of a fatal error on that end, I'd like to throw back a 500 Server Error (unless there's a better method).

Here's my PHP.  Note that `fb()` is a procedural call to FirePHP's logger.

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://otherserver.com/cgi-bin/myCgiScript.cgi");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result === false) {
    $errno = curl_errno($ch);
    $error = curl_error($ch);
    print "errno:\n";
    var_dump($errno);
    print "error:\n";
    var_dump($error);
} else {
    print "result:\n";
    var_dump($result);
}
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
print "info:\n";
var_dump($info);

curl_close($ch);
```

And here is a sample Perl CGI file from the other server:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;
use Try::Tiny;

my $q = new CGI();

try {

   # Code that might die().

   print $q->header({
      -type => "application/json",
      -status => "200 OK"
   });

   print $results;

} catch {
   my $message = $_;
   chomp($message);

   print $q->header({
      -type => "application/json",
      -status => "500 Server Error",
      -message => $message
   });

};
```

But no matter what I do, I can't seem to get the "message" text out of cURL.  (Nor can I get the "Server Error" portion of the "500 Server Error".  I get the fact that I got a 500 error, but no text to go along with it.

Edit:

I simplified the PHP example.

Now it's not following the "failure" path... i.e. it's simply returning `""` if I have `CURLOPT_HEADER = 0`, or the text of the 500 Server Error if `CURLOPT_HEADER = 1`:

```
result:
string(398) "HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error
Date: Fri, 22 Aug 2014 15:32:38 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0e
Message: malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 (before "(end of string)") at /opt/apache/cgi-bin/CSU_SIGNUP_2.0/getCsuAttributes.cgi line 45
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json

"
info:
array(20) {
  ["url"]=>
  string(46) "http://otherserver.com/cgi-bin/myCgiScript.cgi"
  ["content_type"]=>
  string(16) "application/json"
  ["http_code"]=>
  int(500)
  ["header_size"]=>
  int(398)
  ["request_size"]=>
  int(113)
  ["filetime"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["ssl_verify_result"]=>
  int(0)
  ["redirect_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["total_time"]=>
  float(1.117776)
  ["namelookup_time"]=>
  float(0.006001)
  ["connect_time"]=>
  float(0.008552)
  ["pretransfer_time"]=>
  float(0.266607)
  ["size_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["size_download"]=>
  float(0)
  ["speed_download"]=>
  float(0)
  ["speed_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["download_content_length"]=>
  float(0)
  ["upload_content_length"]=>
  float(0)
  ["starttransfer_time"]=>
  float(1.11773)
  ["redirect_time"]=>
  float(0)
}
```

Comment: (1) Boil the example down to something useful - the Perl just needs to raise a 500 error, don't mess with JSON etc. The PHP doesn't need multiple requests or success handling - just check the error code and then look for a message. Then, (2) show us what you actually *do* get back.

Comment: Edited the example to be simpler, provided output.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do a redirect something like this...

```
header( 'Location: http://www.yoursite.com/error.php?error=5000' ) ;
```

And let your php and use $_GET[error']; and let php do the work from there?

Comment: I suppose I could.  I was hoping for something a little more elegant. (i.e., I would like `curl_exec()` to return `false` and be able to pass along an error message retrievable from either `curl_error()` or `curl_getinfo()`.

Comment: I haven't used curl to much and what little i have done i just google :( wish i knew more about it. Im with you would be nice to get away from header location....

Answer (score 0):

You've said your content-type is JSON, but it isn't ("malformed JSON string"). Set a content-type of text for the error and you should be OK.